# RGBDSLAM map recording

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, All,

I am able to run rgbdslam (with openni camera) on fuerte. My question is how can I save the 3d map (as a video?) that is been built. I thought about using rosbag to record all published topics, but how can I visualize the 3D map? I know I can visualize octomap related topics in rviz, what about the 3D map with the image overlay (the map on the rgbdslam GUI)? Thanks a lot for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70657/rgbdslam-map-recording/) by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do I understand correctly that you would like a video of the incremental creation of the point cloud map?

I once tried to extend rgbdslam's gui class to store screenshots of the 3D visualization to disk, but unfortunately it didn't work out.

You can run `recordmydesktop` (or `gtk-recordMyDesktop`) to capture the rgbdslam window, but that's probably rather slow.

Otherwise, you could save the clouds to pcd files (from rgbdslam) and then manipulate the files with a script, using pcd_viewer to display and save a snapshot of each state.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0